# Python: Read large CSV in chunk

Tags: python-3.x

Requirement: Read large CSV file (>1million rows) in chunk

Issue: Sometimes the generator yields the same set of rows twice even though the file has unique rows. But some runs it looks fine with no duplicates

Looks like I am missing something in the code, I am not able to figure out

Want to make sure it doesn't yield the same object over and over with different contents

Code:

```
def gen_chunks(self,reader, chunksize=100000):
    chunk = []
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        if (i % chunksize == 0 and i > 0):
            yield list(map(tuple, chunk))
            chunk = []
        chunk.append(line)
    yield list(map(tuple, chunk))

def execute(self, context):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f_source:
        s3_client.download_file(self.s3_bucket, self.s3_key, f_source.name)
        with open(f_source.name, 'r') as f:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
            for chunk in self.gen_chunks(csv_reader):
                logger.info('starting in chunk process')
                orcl.bulk_insert_rows(table=self.oracle_table,rows=chunk, target_fields=self.target_fields,  commit_every=10000)
```

Comment: See https://pythonspeed.com/articles/faster-pandas-dask/

Comment: I will look into it but for now, I cannot install new libraries in Airflow in our prod env. The above code doesn't have a memory issue

Comment: It will yield various results even when using the exact same source data?

Comment: @Mike67 Yes I am using the same source data, but runs once

Answer (score 0):

Idk if you have an option to try pandas, if yes then this could possibly be your answer.
I find pandas faster when working with millions of records in a csv,
here is some code that will help you

```
import pandas as pd

chunks = pd.read_csv(f_source.name, delimiter="|", chunksize=100000)
for chunk in chunks:
    for row in chunk.values:
        print(row)
```

pandas provides a lot of options with read_csv :
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Will below work with your above pandas code
```for chunk in chunks:
       orcl.bulk_insert_rows(table=self.oracle_table,rows=list(map(tuple, chunk)), target_fields=self.target_fields,  commit_every=10000)```

Comment: Haven't used oracle, but imo **list(map(tuple, chunk))** here will do your job

Comment: I tried using Pandas as you mentioned but got an error as
`[2020-10-03 22:30:46,505] {taskinstance.py:1145} ERROR - Error: ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format`

Comment: Sample Data `311052|0|"Mobile SSU"|"12-Nov-18"|"Cancelled"|"essentials"|""|"F"|19.99|"month"|""`